# Nuget Package Manager GUI not finding the correct packages

Tags: c#, configuration, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating some nuGet packages and everything is well creating until I am trying to find them in the Package Manager. I created my local feed to be **C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder** within that structure I have folders that I have categorized for different lines of businesses in the company.

The nuGet Package Manager GUI only traverses to **C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Categorization\nuget package sits inside here**.

I am trying to make it traverse to **C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Categorization\ProjectFolder\nuget package sits inside here**

What I am trying to figure out is why it does not go deeper in the folder structure to find the .nupkg file, if it goes down one folder deeper by itself while setting up my feed to just be this **C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder** how can I make it go **N** levels deep until it finds all .nupkg?

Comment: Just a guess, do you have more than 255 characters on packages full path?

Comment: Another suggestion would be to install a nuget http server on your machine. It is very easy to setup it.

Comment: No the full path is 125 characters, how would the http server work and how do you set it up? @DavidC

Comment: The server is a nuget package named NuGet.Server. Setup is explained here:  [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was making multiple feeds for my specific categorizations. That way it actually scanned all the project folders and found the nuget package for it.